# Making a COM+ installation package in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, .net-2.0, com+

I recently got tasked with simplifying a COM+ installation consisting of 5-6 COM+ apps for w2k3 server, never having worked with COM+ before. I've seen [some ways to do this with a vbscript](http://www.carlosag.net/Articles/configureComPlus.aspx), but I would much prefer doing it in C#. So I've been searching around and I can't seem to find anything similar for C#.

I am limited to using .NET 2.0, is this feasible? I have been looking for a COM related library, but so far I don't see what I could use.

I would appreciate any pointers you guys might have on how to achieve this, and I will also probably be posting a number of other newbie COM+ questions along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something that will help you -- take a look at the [System.EnterpriseServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.aspx) namespace.

You will have to [jump through some hoops](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030501.htm) to get your .NET assemblies registered as COM objects, but that should be a decent starting point.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I have something to start with.

Comment: Oh, and this is very feasible in any version of .NET.